# What should be innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size for pool_size=2G, pool_instances=2?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have 4G VPS with following config

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2048M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2

SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size/1024/1024
128.00000000
```

Should I change innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size or let it be default?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA 3.9G

Comment: Since you may never use `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size`, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should leave the [innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size) "as is".

[Last year, Percona published some nice formulas to figure out the best chunk size](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/06/19/chunk-change-innodb-buffer-pool-resizing/)

```
determine_best_chunk_size{
  if innodb_buffer_pool_size / innodb_buffer_pool_instances < innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size
  then
    innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = roundDownMB(innodb_buffer_pool_size / innodb_buffer_pool_instances)
  fi
}
determine_amount_of_chunks{
  innodb_buffer_amount_chunks_per_instance = roundDown(innodb_buffer_pool_size / innodb_buffer_pool_instances / innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size)

  if innodb_buffer_amount_chunks_per_instance * innodb_buffer_pool_instances * innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size - innodb_buffer_pool_size > 1024*1024
  then
    innodb_buffer_amount_chunks_per_instance++
  fi
}

determine_best_chunk_size
determine_amount_of_chunks

innodb_buffer_pool_size = innodb_buffer_pool_instances * innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_amount_chunks_per_instance
```

Since you have only 2GB for the Buffer Pool, it is definitely not worth the effort to do any tuning,

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information and formulas related to your question in the [MySQL 5.7 Reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html#:~:text=Chunk%20size%20is%20defined%20by%20the%20innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size%20configuration%20option,is%20equal%20to%20or%20a%20multiple%20of%20innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size%20*%20innodb_buffer_pool_instances.):

> Chunk size is defined by the [innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size) configuration option, which has a default of 128M. For more information, see [Configuring InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html#innodb-buffer-pool-chunk-size).
>
> Buffer pool size must always be equal to or a multiple of [innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size) * [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances). If you configure [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) to a value that is not equal to or a multiple of [innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size) * [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances), buffer pool size is automatically adjusted to a value that is equal to or a multiple of [innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size) * [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances).